# How to show $E[X^k]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}((i+1)^k-i^k)P(X>i)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

where $X$ is a nonnegative integer valued random variable

I can show the case when k=1, but I am completely stuck on the general case. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is useful. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Well, that's what your title is asking for.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. I fixed it now

Comment: What is your definition for the expectation of a function of a random variable?

Comment: $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} iP(X=i)$

Comment: Ok, so $E[X^k] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^k P(X = i)$. Is this statement what your definition would say? From here we need to telescope, I will explain once you understand this part.

Comment: Okay yes, I understand that's what the definition would be. But how would telescoping work in this case?

Comment: $P(X=i)=P(X\gt i-1)-P(X\gt i)$.  You should be able to continue.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not seeing how to connect the dots on this one

Comment: I hope herb's answer below helps, it shows how his hint works. Essentially it is a telescoping argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb P(X=i+1)=\Bbb P(X>i)−\Bbb P(X>i+1)$, and $0^k\Bbb P(X>0)=0$.

Therefore:- $$\begin{align}\Bbb E(X^k)&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^k\Bbb P(X=j)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)^k\Bbb P(X=i+1)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)^k(\Bbb P(X> i)-\Bbb P(X> i+1))\\&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)^k\Bbb P(X> i)-\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)^k\Bbb P(X> i+1)\end{align}$$  However:- $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)^k\Bbb P(X> i+1)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^k\Bbb P(X> i)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i^k\Bbb P(X>i)\end{align}$$ ... so:- $$\Bbb E(X^k)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty ((i+1)^k-i^k)\,\Bbb P(X> i)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $P(X > i) = \sum_{j > i}P(X = j)$ and then change the order of summation.

Another way: Summation by parts.